# JLabel value not changing in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, model-view-controller, jlabel

```
public class Glass extends Observable {
   int amount;
   int capacity;
   public Glass(int amount, int capacity){
       this.amount = amount;
       this.capacity = capacity;
   }
   public int getAmount(){
       return this.amount;
   }

   @Override
   public synchronized void addObserver(Observer o) {
       super.addObserver(o);
       this.setChanged();
       this.notifyObservers();
   }
}

public class GlassLiquidView extends JLabel implements Observer {

    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
         javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                this.setText("" + ((Glass) o).getAmount());
            }
        });

    }

public class GUIControl {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void showGUI() {  

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyFrame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        GlassLiquidView firstGlassLiqView = new  GlassLiquidView();
        GlassLiquidView secondGlassLiqView = new  GlassLiquidView();
        GlassLiquidView thirdGlassLiqView = new  GlassLiquidView();

        Glass [] glasses = new int[3];
        glasses[0] = new Glass(6,6);
        glasses[1] = new Glass(1,4);
        glasses[2] = new Glass(0,3);

        glasses[0].addObserver(firstGlassLiqView);
        glasses[1].addObserver(secondGlassLiqView);
        glasses[2].addObserver(thirdGlassLiqView);

        frame.getContentPane().add(firstGlassLiqView);
        frame.getContentPane().add(secondGlassLiqView);
        frame.getContentPane().add(thirdGlassLiqView);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


        // Amount is changed in from and to glasses
        move(from, to);

        glasses[0].notifyObservers();
        glasses[1].notifyObservers();
        glasses[2].notifyObservers();


    }
```

The JLabels in the GUI does not update after move is called. Note that move is some method that changes the amount in "from" and "to" glasses. The JLabel values are set to the original amount when the glasses were created and no changes appear on the JLabels when move is called. However, when I actually print the amount, it is changed.

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 'move` (or something called by it) sets the text of the `JLabel`s?

Comment: UI changes should be made from event dispatching thread. It is common to make it in response to UI object event and from its event listener or from some Timer or SwingWorker. Worst, invokeLater code as the name suggest   maybe run after your call to move.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Move just changes the "amount" attribute of the glass.

Comment: Could someone please show me how to fix this current code.

Comment: You have to do your `setText` inside a `Runnable` invoked with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.  You have a perfect example at the top of `main` that you can use as a template.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Ok. I am trying to follow the MVC in the project I’m currently working on. Does my current code have bad design or is it normal practice to put code inside a runnable invokes with SwingUtilities.invokeLater for classes that “view” the model?

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès Is it bad design if I use invokeLater thread inside my method? Is there any alternative better way?

Comment: It's not bad design, it's _necessary_ design.

Comment: @JackKong there is no "better" way, you must call any UI update code from the event dispatching thread. There is several solutions for that and one can be call invokeLater or such.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Please have a look at my "public class GlassLiquidView extends JLabel implements Observer" in the code above. I am getting an error for some reason.

Comment: I suspect you are not calling `setChanged` and `notifyObservers` in `move`.

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää "The method setText(String) is undefined for the type new Runnable(){}". This is the error I am getting inside the GlassLiquidView class in the run() method

Comment: Ah. You need to use `GlassLiquidView.this` to get access to the enclosing `GlassLiquidView` instance.

Comment: Show the `move` method.